# Question has the answer, right after the 3rd edit. Why wasn't it noticed by future edits/mods?

Tags: support, protected-questions

Refer Question : [Twitter Bootstrap 3 Sticky Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17966140/2142994)

The answer to the question is given in the question itself!

[image]

There are no answers chosen & the answer is right in the question when it was marked protected.

My question : What do we do with such questions? Its not right to have the answer in the question.

**Edit**

***Why wasn't it noticed that the OP had answered his question right in his 3rd edit?*** And there have been 4 edits after that!

[image]

Comment: Did you see it was protected by Community, which automatically happens after a bunch of poor quality answers from low-rep users are deleted? Can you rewrite your question so it states what you actually want to happen?

Comment: @CodeCaster Doesn't the question go through reviews before going to "protected"?

Comment: Again, what do you want to have happened? Should the question _not_ have been protected, and if so, why not? Or what do you want? As for your edit: the answer should be edited out and posted as a community wiki answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster its good that the question is protected to avoid irrelevant answers. But what I am saying is, this question would have gone through review before that, why wasn't it noticed that the OP has posted the answer in the question itself instead of posting it as an answer?

Comment: The question being protected is unrelated to the fact that the OP posted their solution in the body of their question. Also, " Community ♦" is a bot that (among other tasks) protects questions when certain conditions are met, like too many deleted answers from low-rep users. There's no review that happens when Community decides to protect a question.

Comment: See [What causes a question to be protected by the Community ♦ user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109116/310998).

Comment: @Louis Yes, my question was what CodeCaster has pointed out below(in the answer). And he has answered it. Thanks.

Comment: @Gothdo Thanks, but my question was what CodeCaster has pointed out below. Not why a question is protected.

Comment: @Gothdo no, the question is not _"What should I do"_. The question is _"Why wasn't this caught"_.

Comment: But well they just wanted to close it as a duplicate after all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement comes down to this:

> Some question which definitely requires editing was protected by Community. Shouldn't the protection have underwent review, so it could have been edited by reviewers?

No, protection doesn't undergo review. See also [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question).

That being said, reviews hardly ever cause a post to be fixed up, so I've [done that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160462/266143).

Comment: Thanks, I saw that you have updated the question now.